# One Dark Theme Font

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to change my VSCode font to this one:
[image]

I already know the name of the font, apparently is [this one](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/2.038R-ro%2F1.058R-it%2F1.018R-VAR), but I have no idea on how to put it in my VSCode, i really need a step-by-step, if any of you guys could help me i'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

you have to type those settings into your settings.json file. It should work properly but you have to install first JetBrains font.

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "editor.lineHeight": 0,
    "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
}
```

Type this and it should normally work ! :D

Comment: Where do I install it to?

Comment: Type JetBrains font and go to their website, then install the zip, unzip it and install all the fonts. Then change the settings in the json file.